# How to apply a SUM operation without grouping the results in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have a table like this one:

| id | group | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GROUP A | 0.641028 |
| 2 | GROUP B | 0.946927 |
| 3 | GROUP A | 0.811552 |
| 4 | GROUP C | 0.216978 |
| 5 | GROUP A | 0.650232 |

If I perform the following query:

```
SELECT `id`, SUM(`value`) AS `sum` FROM `test` GROUP BY `group`;
```

I, obviously, get:

| id | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.10281205177307 |
| 2 | 0.946927309036255 |
| 4 | 0.216977506875992 |

But I need a table like this one:

| id | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.10281205177307 |
| 2 | 0.946927309036255 |
| 3 | 2.10281205177307 |
| 4 | 0.216977506875992 |
| 5 | 2.10281205177307 |

Where summed rows are explicitly repeated.

Is there a way to obtain this result without using multiple (nested) queries?

Comment: join your query results back onto the table using `group`

Comment: You are doing multiple things, so multiple queries (nested) are required

Comment: Change `GROUP BY group` to `GROUP BY id` - does that return the expected results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IT would depend on your SQL server, in Postgres/Oracle I'd use Window Functions. In MySQL... not possible afaik.

Perhaps you can fake it like this:

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(b.value) AS `sum`
FROM test AS a
JOIN test AS b ON a.`group` = b.`group`
GROUP BY a.id, b.`group`;
```

Comment: +1 this one is syntactically correct and gives the correct answer.

Comment: GROUP BY a.id is enough, don't need to group by a.id and b.group;

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't AFAIK. You will have to use a join like

```
SELECT t.`id`, tsum.sum AS `sum`
FROM `test` as t GROUP BY `group`
JOIN (SELECT `id`, SUM(`value`) AS `sum` FROM `test` GROUP BY `group`) AS tsum
     ON tsum.id = t.id
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN (SELECT `id`, SUM(`value`) AS `sum` FROM `test` GROUP BY `group`) AS tsum
 ' at line 3