# Using SUM() without grouping the results

Tags: mysql, sum

I already read [(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381053/how-to-apply-a-sum-operation-without-grouping-the-results-in-sql), but couldn't figure out a way to implement it to my specific problem. I know `SUM()` is an aggregate function and it doesn't make sense not to use it as such, but in this specific case, I have to `SUM()` all of the results while maintaining every single row.

Here's the table:

```
--ID-- --amount--
  1        23
  2        11
  3        8
  4        7
```

I need to `SUM()` the amount, but keep every record, so the output should be like:

```
--ID-- --amount--
  1        49
  2        49
  3        49
  4        49
```

I had this query, but it only sums each row, not all results together:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    SUM(b.amount)

FROM table1 as a 
JOIN table1 as b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY id
```

Without the `SUM()` it would only return one single row, but I need to maintain all ID's...

Note: Yes this is a pretty basic example and I could use php to do this here,but obviously the table is bigger and has more rows and columns, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, b.amount
FROM table1 a
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(amount) amount FROM table1
) b
```

You need to perform a [cartesian join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) of the value of the sum of every row in the table to each `id`. Since there is only one result of the subselect (`49`), it basically just gets tacked onto each `id`.

Comment: I get an error:
`[HY000][1137] Can't reopen table: 'a'`

Comment: what if i have multiple categories like a.id,a.name,a.location ? will it still sum based on a.id ??

Answer (score 16):

With `MS SQL` you can use  `OVER()`

```
 select id, SUM(amount) OVER()
 from table1;

select id, SUM(amount) OVER()
from (
  select 1 as id, 23 as amount
  union all
  select 2 as id, 11 as amount
  union all
  select 3 as id, 8 as amount
  union all
  select 4 as id, 7 as amount
) A
```

[image]

```
--- OVER PARTITION ID
```

`PARTITION BY` which is very useful when you want to do `SUM()` per MONTH for example or do quarterly reports sales or yearly...
(Note needs `distinct` it is doing for all rows)

```
 select distinct id, SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY id) as [SUM_forPARTITION]
 from (
     select 1 as id, 23 as amount
     union all
     select 1 as id, 23 as amount
     union all
     select 2 as id, 11 as amount
     union all
     select 2 as id, 11 as amount
     union all
     select 3 as id, 8 as amount
     union all
     select 4 as id, 7 as amount
) OverPARTITIONID
```

[image]

Comment: I must be wrong, but did you seriously write out every single value from the database? That's not very programmatic and therefore not very helpful.

Comment: it is example, you can replace "FROM (...) with you complex query.. The second example is with PARTITION BY which is very useful when you want to do SUM() per MONTH for example

Comment: Take a vote! My first time when the obvious right answer it's not the answer :)

Comment: Edit: Missed mysql tag, but just checked and this code works with MySQL 8.0

Comment: yes Stefan if you add a proper index on "Partition ID" it is deadly, I like very much this approach than CROSS OVER and INNER JOIN

Answer (score 6):

Join the original table to the sum with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table1 AS amount) t
```

Comment: @Bohemian, look closer, the subquery is not in the `SELECT` clause but is in fact part of the `FROM` clause which creates a cartesian product. It only executes once.

Answer (score 0):

This does just one `sum()` query, so it should perform OK:

```
SELECT a.id, b.amount
FROM table1 a
cross join (SELECT SUM(amount) as amount FROM table1 AS amount) b
```

Comment: I like answers that are the same as the accepted answer repeated -- almost as much as I like the answer that it was copied from! Same query, just not formatted neatly.

Answer (score 0):

in case someone else has the same problem and without joining we can do the following

```
select *
,totcalaccepted=(select sum(s.acceptedamount)  from cteresult s)
, totalpay=(select sum(s.payvalue)  from cteresult s)     
from cteresult  t
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Full Join -

case when you need sum of `amount` field from `tableB` and all data from `tableA` on behalf of id match.

```
  SELECT  a.amount, b.* FROM tableB b 
  full join (
      select id ,SUM(amount) as amount FROM tableA 
      where id  = '1' group by id
  ) a 
  on a.id = b.id where a.id ='1' or b.id  = '1' limit 1;
```