# AVG() without grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, average

In MySQL, I have this Query / Table

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        (SELECT MY_FUNCTION(id)) AS rating -- Function returns a float
    FROM my_table
    WHERE
    /* Very long WHERE */
) AS ratings

id              rating
----------      -------------
1               1.00
2               2.00
3               10.00
4               11.05
5               10.04
```

Now I try to get the avereage rating

```
SELECT *, AVG(rating)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        (SELECT MY_FUNCTION(id)) AS rating -- Function returns a float
    FROM my_table
    WHERE
    /* Very long WHERE */
) AS ratings

id              rating          AVG(rating)
----------      -------------   -------------
1               1.00            6,818
```

Because AVG() is an aggregate function, the other lines are stripped. I would like (not like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357640/using-sum-without-grouping-the-results)) to keep the lines like this, **without** doing another select on `my_table`, because the WHERE is too complex to do it twice. Like this:

```
id              rating          AVG(rating)
----------      -------------   -------------
1               1.00            6,818
2               2.00            6,818
3               10.00           6,818
4               11.05           6,818
5               10.04           6,818
```

I also tried this: [Using SUM() without grouping the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357640/using-sum-without-grouping-the-results) but I can't get the CROSS JOIN to work with the table alias or without doing the complex WHERE part twice.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Ratings (
ID Int Not Null,
Rating Float Not Null
)
Insert Ratings (ID, Rating) 
Select ID, MyFunction(ID)
From my_table
--Where yaadddyaddd

Declare @Average float 
Select @Average = Avg(Rating) From Ratings
Select ID, Rating, @Average
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about can be done with a simple OAF (ordered analytical function):

```
SELECT foo.*
    ,AVG(rating) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rating
FROM my_table AS foo
WHERE bar = /* many crazy shitz */
```

This will give you the `AVG` function for the entire table, spread across all rows.

Comment: Does mysql have windowing functions?

Comment: oh boo, i didnt see the MySQL part. damn.

Comment: So no alternative? ;) A temporary table is a possibility, but it seems a little bit overkill