# SUM() without group by per name without definitive ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

suppose I have this database :

```
Name         Price
447          1500
501          1000
574          1510
574          680
574          400
574          890
```

I want the end result is like this :

```
Name         Price
447          1500
501          1000
574          3480
574          3480
574          3480
574          3480
```

Where 3480 is the sum result of price with name 574. I saw [some solutions with partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357640/using-sum-without-grouping-the-results), but require a definitive id, while mine don't have it. I tried it too with cross join but mine can't work since it sums all not separately based its name. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.name,
       (select sum(t2.price) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name) as price
from t;
```