# Total sum of a column in a table that's used created by groupby

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

For the example below, I'm wondering how to obtain the total (i.e. the sum of all of the rows in SUM(total_cost). It seems like this should be easy but I've been trying for quite some time now and am still stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologize for the "noobishness" of this question.

```
SELECT cate_id,SUM(total_cost)
FROM purchase            
GROUP BY cate_id;

+---------+-----------------+
| cate_id | SUM(total_cost) |
+---------+-----------------+
| CA001   |         1725.00 | 
| CA002   |          965.00 | 
| CA003   |          900.00 | 
+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?

  
    | CA001   |         3590.00 | 
    | CA002   |         3590.00 | 
    | CA003   |         3590.00 | 
  
Then Check this, Similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357640/using-sum-without-grouping-the-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT cate_id, SUM(total_cost)
FROM purchase            
GROUP BY cate_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

This will add a new row with the total.

Comment: WITH ROLLUP was an extremely helpful term to lookup, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For a general solution across RDBMs, consider `UNION` query without grouping:

```
SELECT cate_id, SUM(total_cost)
FROM purchase            
GROUP BY cate_id

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, SUM(total_cost)
FROM purchase
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to use the `group by` or need to show all of the ids the cleanest solution should be:

```
select sum(total_cost) from purchase;
```

This gives the output : `3590`